# Linking C++ in SciTE

Tags: c++, g++, scite

I just started using SciTE and I really like it, but at the moment I'm having a bit of a problem.

When I make a simple "hello world" with just one file everything works just fine. But when I start to add other files I get problems linking causing undefined references.

`g++ $(ccopts) -c $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).o`

That's the command in my cpp.properties. Everything is at the default.

I have main.cpp and an a.cpp and a.h.

How can I configure this to account for multiple files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile multiple file do this

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o
g++ a.cpp    -o a.o
g++ main.o a.o -o program
```

then run with

```
./program
```

I simple make file might look like

Makefile

```
CC=g++

all: program

program: main.o a.o
    $(CC) $< -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```